# Use nginx as reverse proxy on plesk with 2 domains and one nodejs server

Tags: node.js, nginx, plesk

I have a Plesk Obisdian 18.0.25, with a domain `staging.product.com` running a NodeJS Server serving my Nuxt.js as a Server Side Rendering application.

Now I want to add multi language support, so I added `staging-fr.product.com`, activated nginx as an reverse proxy. `staging.product.com` still works, as expected, but I can't get the reverse Proxy on `staging-fr` working.

This is my additional config for Nginx on `staging-fr` (from https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/)

```
location ~ / {

    proxy_redirect                      off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_pass                          http://staging.product.com; # tried many different domains, localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000 and others
}
```

I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Also, I can't find a running node process, and `sudo netstat -tulpen` didn't show me any running processes.

I know that nodejs is running with Passenger, but I can't find any configuration in plesk.

I just want to use the second domain to decide the language according to https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/different-domains.html

- What should be the proxy_pass?
- Can I start a Node-Server without an domain?

Comment: can you share nginx configuration of `staging.product.com` ?

Comment: I deactivated nginx for `staging.product.com`, it is currently directly served

Comment: I just want to use the fr-domain to decide the language according to https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/different-domains.html, both on the same node-instance

Comment: `proxy_pass` should be the same as `proxy_pass` of `staging.product.com` domain, but its not `proxy_pass                          http://staging.product.com;`

Comment: `staging` is not running nginx, so no configuration. staging is directly served, and staging-fr should be proxied to staging